# Send message to everyone connected to LAN

Tags: networking, operating-system, browser

I want to send a message to everyone(broadcast) in my subnet(LAN) so as to prevent them using Internet due to repair work that's going to happen. How do i do that ? I can't use "wall" because no one is logged on some server.
I want to send a packet that opens a new Tab in web browser and displays message that stop using Internet during a certain duration.

Comment: Imagine any website could open tabs in your browser. You probably wouldn't like it. Do your users use email?

Comment: okk if not browser then do we any others method of informing. Not everyone has email on the mail server.

Comment: If you have the phone nunbers of the people, connected to the LAN, you can send them SMS.

Comment: Just cut off their internet, and when they call *you*, tell them what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

you can use sockets to send a message to everyone connected in LAN, you can use java and when you want send a message to all clients, every client will see a msgbox with the information you want display....

Comment: socket needs listening server. How will you communicate when no listening process is there on hosts?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing

You might be interested in something like this. I am not sure if this will work in your LAN environment, but typically it should mess up with the entire LAN :D

Comment: sir, I don't to bombard the LAN with ARP packets. Instead I want to send users in the subnet to receive message like a pop box or in new tab of browser that- please close you connections or transactions as network is being serviced. If i choke the network then may be someone doing a transaction will cry out :P

Answer (score 0):

`net send` command will be helpful in windows machines. Im not sure about linux.

Plz refer the following link for more Info.

http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/net-send-command/

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution shared by my senior( Hope it helps anyone who views this post). What we  can do is to do DNS spoofing and redirect everyone's request to a server where you can  show the required message.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to scan your LAN and save in some list only computers and theirs IP addresses. I am an author of an [ShixxNOTE program](https://www.shixxnote.com) which is network enabled desktop sticky notes program. You must have installed your program on all clients or computers in your LAN. Then you need to open socket port and start listener on some port e.g. 3560. If you want to send message to others in your LAN you need to send your dana incuding message to clients. I can help you with code which will scan your LAN and will fino all computers in it. Then it is up to you to create client/server app. You can also use MSG command instead of sending data through socket port. But first you need is to find all computers by name and IP addresses.